# Multiple find results handling

Tags: mongodb, go, model

I am storing users and treating them as the center of the universe in my application, i am now trying to introduce the concept of an Org whereby users can be a member of many Orgs and then certain settings etc will belong to the Org. The function I am trying to create is to search for all Orgs where the users ID can be found and either the Owner or one of the Members and return a list of Orgs to then render the details client-side.

The issue I am having relates to the handling and conversion of results from the Mongo Find and then how to handle that and convert to a format I can return safely at the end.

Currently im unable to return the data with the error

> cannot use &org (value of type *[]*model.Org) as *model.Org value in
>   return statement

**Org Model**

package model

```
// Org is the structure of a org
type Org struct {
    ID          string   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name        string   `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Owner       string   `json:"owner" bson:"owner"`
    Members     []string `json:"members" bson:"members"`
    Token       string   `json:"token" bson:"-"`
    VerifyToken string   `json:"verifyToken" bson:"verifyToken"`
}
```

**Function**

```
// GetOrgByUserID returns a user by his id
func (db *DB) GetOrgByUserID(id string) (*model.Org, error) {
    findOptions := options.Find()

    var org []*model.Org

    cur, err := db.collections.orgs.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"owner", id}}, findOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Iterate through the cursor
    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var elem model.Org
        err := cur.Decode(&elem)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        org = append(org, &elem)
    }

    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Close the cursor once finished
    cur.Close(context.TODO())

    return &org, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix by declaring the return value as a slice. Also, simplify the code by using the [cursor All](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All) method:

```
func (db *DB) GetOrgByUserID(id string) ([]*model.Org, error) {
    findOptions := options.Find()
    cur, err := db.collections.orgs.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"owner", id}}, findOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer cur.Close(ctx.TODO())
    var org []*model.Org
    err = cur.All(ctx.TODO(), &org)
    return org, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks although there actually can be multiple results (orgs) that the user can be an owner/member of..

Comment: Does not seem to be a function for ALL

    cur.All undefined (type mongo.Cursor has no field or method All)

Comment: @medoix Use package version [1.1.0](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.1.0/mongo?tab=doc#Cursor.All) or later.  Otherwise, replace the call to All with the loop from the code in the question.

Comment: cur.ALL required the context to be passed and the return org still errors "cannot use org (variable of type []*model.Org) as *model.Org value in return statement"

Comment: @medoix See first line of code in the answer. Declare the return value as the slice type `[]*model.Org`.

Comment: Thank you i had indeed missed that. Seems the DB model is now not expecting that type of result as i get this error

`pkg/db/db.go:38:2: cannot use db (type *mongodb.DB) as type DB in return argument:
 *mongodb.DB does not implement DB (wrong type for GetOrgByUserID method)
  have GetOrgByUserID(string) ([]*model.Org, error)
  want GetOrgByUserID(string) (*model.Org, error)
`

Comment: Use the slice type in all code that works with multiple Org values.